# Magento 2.2 - Need same images for different products

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, magento2.2, magento2.2.2

I need to make a configurable product with 4 Products ( A, B, C, D) of different colors. All the products have 4 photos but 3 of the photos are exactly the same in every product. They have exactly the same file name and data. So i need all the products to use the same file and not duplicate (as i have less storage on my server and there are a lot of products like this).

My images go under media/catalog/product/i/p/filename1.jpg. Rather than using the existing file, Magento makes a copy of this file as filename1_1.jpg.

Ive tried to import the products using csv file but its failing on creating a Configurable Product so I will have to do it manually.

Is there any way i can use already existing photos on different products.

Comment: whether the product is different.you need to upload images seperately.add same images to different products affect your further product  image modifications & deletions

Comment: @Tanish if you insist to do this, you can modify or create sql script to modify the database, if i'm not mistaken the product image url was stored iniside the databse using json_decode

Answer (score 1):

copy product images from one product to other

```
public function copyProductImages($productSrc,$productDest)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
        $baseDir = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
    
        $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $productSrc->getMediaGalleryEntries();
        $allImages = array();
        if (count($existingMediaGalleryEntries) > 0) {
            foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
                $is_label = $entry->getLabel();
                $file = $baseDir .'catalog/product'. $entry->getData('file');
                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    if (!isset($images[$file])) {
                       $allImages[$file] = array();
                    }
                    $allImages[$file] = $entry->getData('types');
                }
            }
        }
        foreach ($allImages as $file => $imageAttributeList) {
            try {
             $productDest->addImageToMediaGallery($file, $imageAttributeList, false, false);
             $productDest->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked for simple to configurable for me!

Answer (score 0):

Magento always creates new image if you upload same images multiple times not only for different products but for same products as well.

This is because if someone upload different images with same name magento cannot understand the images are different or same, thats why it creates new one with _1.jpg, _2.jpg or so on rather than replacing the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I use now the program "EmagicOne" to import simple and configurable items with picture shared. (Just a setting in the import). It saves me a lot of space.